# Visual Studio Code Ubuntu - The mode has failed while tokenizing the input

Tags: c#, .net, ubuntu, visual-studio-code, ubuntu-16.04

I installed VS Code on Ubuntu 16.04 and when I click on any file in my .NET solution I get the following message 'The mode has failed while tokenizing the input.' I thought maybe this was from upgrading from preview to the newest version but I've uninstalled and reinstalled and tried both 64 bit and 32 bit versions. I have had not luck. Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: It appears to be a problem with the Github VS on ubuntu..
[The mode has failed while tokenizing the input. #8950](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/8950)

Comment: Have you installed the C# extension? You also need to let it download OmniSharp from the Internet.

Comment: I did install the C# extension. I originally thought this was what was causing the issue so I uninstalled it but the issue continued.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be an issue when updating on Debian packages, see [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/8876).

The solution that worked for me was suggested [in this comment](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/8876#issuecomment-231425705):

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/share/code/resources/app/node_modules/vscode-textmate/node_modules
```